# Agregar/Quitar Onkeydown="return false" en <Body> usando código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onkey, body

Buen día a todos, tengo una página que contiene `Onkeydown='return false'` en su `<body>` lo que inhabilita el uso de el teclado. Pero necesito que éste se pueda activar en un momento dado, más específicamente para escribir en un `input`, para lo que es necesario quitar el Onkeydown pero quiero que se vuelva a habilitar una vez terminada la acción de escribir en el `input`.
Mi pregunta es:
¿hay alguna manera de poder quitar el `onkeydown` del `<body>` para poder escribir en el `input`, y luego de eso, poder volver a poner el `onkeydown` nuevamente en el `<body>` mediante JavaScript?
Muchas Gracias por su atención. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Hay una razón específica para deshabilitar el teclado?

Creo que es una muy mala idea y explico con un ejemplo: Muchas veces uso el teclado en vez del mouse para desplazarme (scroll) en las páginas o, incluso para retroceder en el historial.

En fin, si no vas a tener en cuenta a usuarios quisquillosos (como tu servidor) ni a otros con capacidades diferentes... sigue leyendo.

No es conveniente asignar el evento en la misma etiqueta `<body onkeydown="return false;">`. Lo más adecuado es crear una función en Javascript donde puedas analizar en qué casos sí vas a permitir el uso del teclado:

```js
// Activar el evento usando una función
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    // El evento no ocurrió en el input donde sí se puede escribir
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase != 'input' && e.target.id != 'si-escribe') {
        // Cancelar evento, no permitir escribir
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="si-escribe" type="text" value="Teclea aquí"><br>
<textarea>Aquí no se puede escribir</textarea>
```